# Replication types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, transactional-replication

How can I find out, if my current replication pattern is any of following or not? I am using SQL2008R2.

1)Peer to peer replication

2)Bidirectional transactional replication

Answer (score 0):

use sp_helppublication

see BoL for full syntax and a description of the result set

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helppublication-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you.. I can find reference for peer to peer but sp_helppublication dont have anything to tell if replication is "Bidirectional transactional replication"

Comment: That is a property of the resultset sp_helpsubscription
look for the value of loopback_detection

Comment: Thank you.. this helped..